# Cascade update sql trigger

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables in two different databases Lab15DB_1 and Lab15DB_2.

The parent table is Author and the child table is Book.

Here they are:

```
CREATE TABLE Author 
(
    AuthorId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AuthorName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    AuthorSurname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Book 
(
    BookId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BookName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    BookType NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK(BookType IN ('Science', 'Hobby', 'Cooking', 'Fishing', 'Nature', 'Favorites')),
    PublishYear INT NOT NULL,
    AuthorId INT NOT NULL,
    Price MONEY CHECK (PRICE > 0.0)
)
```

I want to create cascade update via triggers.

Here is an attempt to create trigger for cascade update on the `Author` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAuthorTrigger
ON Author 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @intRowCount int

    SELECT @intRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @intRowCount > 1
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(AuthorId)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Author 
            SET AuthorId = AuthorId
            /* some code for update Book*/
        END
    END
    ELSE
        IF @intRowCount = 1
        BEGIN
            IF UPDATE(AuthorId)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Author
                SET Author.AuthorId = (SELECT AuthorId FROM INSERTED)
                FROM Author 
                INNER JOIN DELETED ON Author.AuthorId = DELETED.AuthorId

                UPDATE Lab15DB_1.dbo.Book
                SET Lab15DB_1.dbo.Book.AuthorId = (SELECT AuthorId FROM INSERTED)
                FROM Lab15DB_1.dbo.Book 
                INNER JOIN DELETED ON Lab15DB_1.dbo.Book.AuthorId = DELETED.AuthorId
            END
        END
GO
```

There is no problem with case `@intRowCount = 1`, but I have difficulties with case `@intRowCount > 1`.

Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "cascade update"?  Why not just declare your foreign key as `on update cascade`/

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but i have to do this via triggers, that is my task.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Specify the DB name

Comment: It *looks* like t-sql, but that doesn't really mean anything. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant rdbms tag.

Comment: Yes, it is t-sql. I've edited my question.

Comment: So SQL Server, then? Why are you updating the primary key column? If you want the books table to be updated when the author id changes, you should go with Gordon's comment as set the foreign key with `on update cascade`.